# Issue while creating JavaPairrRDD using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have data in below format

```
Product1
somelines...
Iteam1
Iteam2

Product1
somelines....
Iteam1
Iteam3
```

I need to make pair as

```
(Product1:Item1,Item2)
(Product1:Item1,Item3)
```

I tried creating it with following java code (Updated for more understanding)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Analyzer").setMaster("local[2]").set("sparkexecutor","1g");
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaPairRDD<String,String> lines = fetchProductData(ctx);   

    static JavaPairRDD<String, String> fetchProductData(JavaSparkContext ctx) {
    JavaRDD<String> productLines = ctx.textFile("C:\\Service.log", 1);
    System.out.println("called" + productLines);
    JavaRDD<String[]> productLineMap = productLines.map(new Function<String, String[]>() {
        String productname = "";
       @Override
        public String[] call(String s) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("test"+s);
                Matcher m = PRODUCTREGEX.matcher(s);
            if(m.find()){
                productname = m.group(1);
                System.out.println("productname"+productname);
            }
            return s.split("\t");
        }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, String> productMapKey = productLineMap.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String[], String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, String> call(String[] strings) throws Exception {
            String[] dataArray = strings[0].split(",");
            String date_s = dataArray[5];
            return new Tuple2<String, String>(dataArray[4], "product");
        }
    });
    return productMapKey;
}
```

}

but my even this statement in code is not executed

```
System.out.println("test"+s);
```

Can any body help me in creating pair. I am using java

Comment: Could you put this code in the full context (`main` method)?

Comment: @zero323 I have updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your debug statement isn't executed because You don't have any action in Your driver program, only transformations. Spark is lazy, it sees that You don't use RDD at all so it doesn't bother computing it.
- Do I get it right, Your data about single product is scattered across multiple lines of input file? In this case I would preprocess this data outside of Spark - Spark has notion of order of individual lines only after sorting, it would be hard or even impossible (not sure) to get it right. I would preprocess this file to make all data about product appear in single line. It wouldn't be a problem even with huge input, with Iterator of lines only small amount of data would be loaded in memory at once.